# can you debug 64bit target apps with Ollydbg 1.1?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I don't really get the difference between 2.0 and 1.1.

the registers aren't even showing up as 64bit format in 2.0.

Also 32bit apps take way too long to process with.

Plugins aren't even fully supported.

Is it possible to debug 64bit apps in 1.1 managing the problems

that I listed above?

I'm using 64bit Windows 8.1 and I;m trying to debug a 64bit sample file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OllyDbg currently does not support debugging 64 bit apps, however the developer stated to start the development of a 64 bit version as soon as his free times allows him. For a 64 bit debugger, take a look at [WinDBG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx).

**Update 2021:** These days, [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com/) is also an excellent choice. Its design is strongly inspired by OllyDbg.

Comment: oh thats too bad :( the 2.0 version just lets ollydbg run on 64 bit os is iy then?

Comment: It's a total rewrite and fixes a lot of flaws from Olly1. It however still has some pretty tedious bugs and still isn't as well supported by plugin developers as Olly1 is. Olly1 works in a SysWOW64 environment (32 bit applications on a 64 bit windows) as well.